# Get record by ID and all foreigns recursive in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've two tables, looks that (migrations):

```
Schema::create('sets', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('key');

    $table->string('name');

    $table->string('set_type');

    $table->integer('belongs_to')->unsigned();

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('belongs_to')->references('id')->on('sets')->onDelete('cascade');

});

Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id');

    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();

    $table->bigInteger('set_id')->unsigned();

    $table->string('post_type', 25);

    $table->text('post');

    $table->boolean('is_reported')->default(false);

    $table->boolean('is_hidden')->default(false);

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('set_id')->references('id')->on('sets');

});
```

The 'set' table is for storing data in which the location (country, city...) the post should be view. For example, let's store some countries:

```
   id | key               | name        | belongs_to
   1  | europe            | Europe      | null
   2  | germany-all       | Germany     | 1
   3  | germany-berlin    | Berlin      | 2
   4  | germany-frankfurt | Frankfurt   | 2
   5  | poland-all        | Poland      | 1
   6  | poland-warsaw     | Warsaw      | 5
   7  | england-all       | England     | 1
```

And, my post has set_id as 6. Looking logically, when I want get posts from Europe (ID 1), that post should be returned too, because 6 belongs to 5, and 5 belongs to 1. And this is that what I want to do. It's possible to do without using too much PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I found the best solution. It's the Nested Set pattern. I used [baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) package and it looks that:

For `sets` table I added Baum's colums:

```
Schema::create('sets', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
   $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->index();
   $table->integer('lft')->nullable()->index();
   $table->integer('rgt')->nullable()->index();
   $table->integer('depth')->nullable();

   $table->string('key');
   $table->string('name');
   $table->string('set_type');

   $table->timestamps();
});
```

And done! Just get set_id's and return posts, for example:

```
$sets = Set::where('key', '=', $myKey)->first()->getDescendantsAndSelf()->lists('id');
$posts = Post::whereIn('set_id', $sets)->with(['user'])->take(6)->get();
```

I’m leave this for posterity ;)

Comment: You can also do `$set = Set::where('key', '=', $myKey)->first()->getDescendantsAndSelf()->list('id');` without using the foreach to loop, because `getDescendantsAndSelf()` returns a collection object.

Comment: @blackpla9ue, idk why, but it returns "Call to undefined method Baum\Extensions\Eloquent\Collection::list()" :/

Comment: Sorry it should be `lists` http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_lists

Answer (score 3):

You need to break down region, country and city into different tables and establish the relationship between these OR
you can list all the combinations in one single table i.e. ID | Region | Country | City so you would have separate row for each city containing the country and the region.

Comment: I could do that, but that solution is just limited. For example, in the future I want add neighborhood to city. And I've a problem. Moreover, some countries has different entities, eg. US has states, in Poland we have voivodships etc. That's why I can't use the solution you have specified.

Comment: @Siper if you break the entities into tables it's easy to expand later with counties, neighbourhoods, etc. Moreover it doesn't really matter what counties are called in different countries as long as they are the equivalent across countries.